# Regex Expression - text between quotes and brackets

Tags: regex

i have the following JSON string that i need to parse:

{'ConnectionDetails':'{\'server\':\'johnssasd02\',\'database\':\'enterprise analytics\'}'}]}

i am already using the expression '([^']*)' to get everything in quotes, which correctly gets me the ConnectionDetails title.  However i now need an expression to get me everything between '{ and '} in order to get the full path value.  so i need to capture the following from above string:

{\'server\':\'johnssasd02\',\'database\':\'enterprise analytics\'}

but having trouble coming up the regex expression

thanks

Comment: It's not a valid **JSON**

Comment: it's just a snippet, full string: {'DatasetId':'cedd1fba-32f2-4671-824e-c59127c71169','DataConnectivityMode':'LiveConnection','Datasources':[{'DatasourceType':'AnalysisServices','ConnectionDetails':'{\'server\':\'johnssasd02\',\'database\':\'enterprise analytics\'}'}],'IsSuccess':true,'RequestId':'3fc38970-e44e-4292-bea1-4354c7c737a5','ActivityId':'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'}

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract the data between the curly braces `{}` you can use the regex: `\{(.*?)\}`

Comment: i think i got it using \{\\(.*?)\}', however i had to update my original expression to find anything between quotes from '([^']*)' to '([^\\']*)' in order to exclude the text between quotes in the server path value.  I need to test it now against the full file to see if it works for all rows

Comment: ok so that didn't entirely work.  I have an expression to find anything between single quotes like this: '([^']*)', but i want it to also ignore any patterns of \' but can't get it to work, any ideas on that one?

Comment: [this](https://ibb.co/vJFGnyF) is what I'm doing, can you please help me understand the blocker

Comment: so the expression you have does get the text between the curly braces, however becasue in the string between the curly brackets there are also items that have single quotes around them like ',\', so my other expression that handles any text around single quotes which is this '([^']*)' is picking up  ',\' so the curly bracket expression doesn't work.  i have to somehow tell  '([^']*)' to negate anthying that has \'

Comment: so i want an expression to find any text between quotes, but the text cannot include a \'.  So 'Test' is ok, but 'Test\' is not

Answer (score 0):

i accomplished it within an SSIS derived column task where i removed unwanted characters from the input string. that way i don't have to worry about dealing with them using regex.